# Need help with the meaning of this sentence, because I got confused by many meanings of 調子に乗り and 勢いをつけて

Tags: meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

**そう言われて調子に乗り、勢いをつけて俺は....**

There's a sentence in an eroge, which I don't understand due to my JP level. Hope someone can help me to understand its correct meaning.
(my guess is : "After she said that, I feel incredibly excited, and with the uplifting spirit she gave to me..." but I'm not sure since there are too many different meanings for "調子に乗り" and "勢いをつけて" )

Context: this is a H-scene in the bathroom between MC and a girl

頬は紅潮し、声も上擦っている。かなり限界という感じだ。俺もだけどっ。

> ペニスを奥へ奥へと突き進めながら、長いストロークで抽挿を行うと、もじもじと身体をくねらせる。

> Girl「ううっ、来てるっ……オマエのチンポっ……グリグリって子宮の入り口まで……届いてるっ！」

> **そう言われて調子に乗り、勢いをつけて俺はリーシャの花芯をズボズボ貫いた。**

(if my understandings was wrong please correct me)

Comment: What is the title of the game? I suggest including citation (author, title, etc) when quoting a long piece of text. Doing so is a good practice in general, and can provide additional context.

Answer (score 2):

調子に乗る is about mind - being too excited (after learning something). 勢いをつける is about motion - having (physical) momentum. It looks like the expected reading is the first motivates the second.

Answer (score 2):

調子に乗る means the state you feel that you're greater than you should feel.

勢いをつけて means "with great force". In this situation, it probably mentions the physical force, though it's sometimes used figuratively.